# vertical-align of text in <li> when resize window and text goes on two lines

Tags: html, css, vertical-alignment

are many days that i want to resolve my problem... but is very difficult:

I would like a vertical alignment for a text in **li**

Many people (in more questions) suggest to use

```
display: table
```

for parent and **display: table-cell** for **li**

is a good idea, but there are problems (padding, margin, floats doesn't works)...

example:

```
<ul>
 <li class="text">
  <span>Text on one line</span>
 </li>
 <li class="text">
  <span> More text on two lines --------</span>
 </li>
</ul>

.text{
 bakground: #e9e9e9;
 list-style: none;
 color: 000;
 height: 40px;
 margin: 5px;
 padding: 3px;
}
```

The better solution is this:

```
.text span{
   position: relative;
   top: 30%;
}
```

for me this is better solution, but there's a problem...
if the text of **li** is on one line is ok, but if is on two lines the text (2° line) goes out of **li**

It needs something that cancels this code when the text is on two lines...

can you help me?

thanks! and sorry for my english

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use flexbox:

```css
.text {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}
```

```css
.text {
  background: #e9e9e9;
  list-style: none;
  height: 40px;
  margin: 5px;
  padding: 3px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li class="text">
    <span>Text on one line</span>
  </li>
  <li class="text">
    <span>More text on two lines<br />--------</span>
  </li>
</ul>
```

If the content can become taller than the flex container and you want to use `overflow` to add some scrolling mechanism, better use [auto margins](http://www.w3.org/TR/css-flexbox-1/#auto-margins).

```css
.text { display: flex; }
.text > span { margin: auto 0; }
```

```css
.text {
  background: #e9e9e9;
  list-style: none;
  height: 40px;
  margin: 5px;
  padding: 3px;
  display: flex;
  overflow: auto;
}
.text > span {
  margin: auto 0;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li class="text">
    <span>Text on one line</span>
  </li>
  <li class="text">
    <span>More text on two lines<br />--------</span>
  </li>
  <li class="text">
    <span>A<br />B<br />C<br />D<br />E<br />F<br />G<br />H</span>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Just make sure you can use flex-box: http://caniuse.com/#feat=flexbox, some browsers still require prefixes and you're out of luck if you're supporting IE 9 or earlier.

Comment: and if i have list-style there's a way with **display:flex** to show also type of  **li**? now there isn't...

Comment: @Giovanni-Borgia Yes, the problem is that with `display: flex` you lose `display: list-item`, and thus the markers disappear. You can try faking the markers with pseudo-elements or using `<li><div class="text">...</div></li>`

Comment: @Oriol no i haven't a pc but i think that adding div with the class inside item i don't resolve nothing because the text inside div it will have a vertical alignment, but a marker of **li** No! :/

Comment: Maybe like you say, a good idea could be the pseudo-element for li. But i don't know how to use it. Maybe i must do a li::after and to add inside **display: last-item** ? I don't like to add **content: "• "**